# How to sort div with select? Like on shopping sides with gender and shoe size

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sort div elements like on e.g. shopping sites with a select. But I dont know how to modify my JS code I have to make multiple selects.

I think my JS Code works but not like this. I dont know why.

```js
const productDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".product");
const categorySelectStudio = document.querySelector("#select-studio");

if (categorySelectStudio) {
  categorySelectStudio.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const category = e.target.value;

    [...productDivs].forEach((pd) => {
      const display = pd.dataset.category === category || category === "all";
      pd.style.display = display ? "" : "none";
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <!--Selecter-->
  <select id="select-studio">
    <option value="all">All studios</option>
    <option value="disney">Walt Disney</option>
    <option value="warner">Warner Bros.</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-month">
    <option value="all">All month</option>
    <option value="jan">January</option>
    <option value="feb">February</option>
    <option value="mar">March</option>
    <option value="apr">April</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-genre">
    <option value="all">All genre</option>
    <option value="action">action film</option>
    <option value="adventure">adventure film</option>
    <option value="animated">animated film</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-type">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="novie">movie</option>
    <option value="serie">serie</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-platform">
    <option value="all">All platform</option>
    <option value="prime">Amazon Prime</option>
    <option value="netflix">Netflix</option>
  </select>

  <!--Releases-->
  <div data-studio="disney" data-month="mar" data-action="action" data-serie="serie" data-platform="disney+" class="product">Dinner</div>
  <div data-category="first meal" class="product">First meal</div>
  <div data-category="garnish" class="product">Garnish</div>
</div>
```

Comment: depending on your limits i would suggest creating the elements in js before adding them to the page, maybe store the elements in an array or objects with distinct properties to call them easier a.e. {{value:"Dinner", studio:"disney",month:"mar",etc:"..."}.{value:"first meal",etc:"..."} } and than construct the list after input on one of the sort elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

```js
document.getElementById("selects").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const vals = [...this.querySelectorAll("select")]
    .map(({id,value}) => ({id,value})) // get all values from selects
  //console.log(vals)
  Object.entries(vals)
    .forEach(([, {id,value}]) => {
      const ds = id.replace("select-", "");
      document.querySelectorAll('#releases div') // all divs with data attribute
        .forEach(div => {
          console.log(ds, value, div.dataset[ds])
          div.classList.toggle("hide", value !== "all" && div.dataset[ds] !== value) // here we need to hide the ones that does NOT have the right attributes
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="selects" class="all">
  <!--Selecter-->
  <select id="select-studio">
    <option value="all">All studios</option>
    <option value="disney">Walt Disney</option>
    <option value="warner">Warner Bros.</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-month">
    <option value="all">All month</option>
    <option value="jan">January</option>
    <option value="feb">February</option>
    <option value="mar">March</option>
    <option value="apr">April</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-genre">
    <option value="all">All genre</option>
    <option value="action">action film</option>
    <option value="adventure">adventure film</option>
    <option value="animated">animated film</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-type">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="movie">movie</option>
    <option value="serie">serie</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-platform">
    <option value="all">All platform</option>
    <option value="disney+">Disney+</option>
    <option value="prime">Amazon Prime</option>
    <option value="netflix">Netflix</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!--Releases-->
<div id="releases">
  <div data-studio="disney" data-month="mar" data-genre="action" data-serie="serie" data-platform="disney+" class="product hide">Winter soldier</div>
  <div data-studio="disney" data-month="mar" data-genre="action" data-serie="serie" data-platform="netflix" class="product hide">Captain America</div>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks for the fast answer. But how can I reset now the filter? But very nice code! Props!

Comment: Maybe someone else has a better answer but huge thanks!

Comment: One step further